# problem for reading table file and storing it in an array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I want to read and store in an array `a` file with `n` lines and `m` columns:

```
8.315287e-07     1.422122e-28    9.128814e-32    8.693229e-28    
1.015631e-06     1.422121e-28    9.128802e-32    8.693270e-28   
1.240495e-06     1.422119e-28    9.128784e-32    8.693241e-28
```

I wrote the following code:

```
FILE* file = NULL;
double intensity[46][7] = {{0}};
int score[2][3];
int kloop = 0;
double sum=0;
file = fopen("intensity", "r");
// if (file = NULL) printf("file = NULL");
for (kloop = 0 ;kloop < 47;kloop ++){
    if (fichier != NULL)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d %d ...", &intensity[i][0],&intensity[i][1]...;
        printf("%e %e \n",intensity[i][0], intensity[i][1]...]);
    }
}
fclose(file);
```

It seems that the code cannot read (or print) the correct numbers cause I'm getting this:

```
4.424023e-315 1.426064e-315 9.885327e-316 1.536630e-315 1.269882e-315  
4.437332e-315 1.426064e-315 9.885326e-316 1.536631e-315 1.269882e-315  
4.447104e-315 1.426064e-315 9.885325e-316 1.536630e-315 1.269882e-315
```

Then I get a  "segmentation fault" error when I uncomment the line 7.
It is working with a simple file which contains integers:

```
1   2   3

4   5   7
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: `fscanf(..., "%d", ..)` -> `fscanf(..., "%lf", ..)`

Comment: Indeed it is working, thanks a lot. Why is %d not valid? I thought it is containing an address so an integer.

Comment: You should check the return value from `fscanf` to see how many values it read in so you can handle errors/failures

Comment: @ludmi You specify what type you want to read in and in this case it is `double` (`%lf`). You always pass the addresses to `scanf` functions since C is pass by value (otherwise they can not be modified).

Comment: The format specifiers (`%s`, `%d`, `%f`,`%lf` and so on) must match the types of the arguments ( `char *`, `int *`, `float *`, `double * `, ...). Do yourself a favour and let the compiler warn you to catch cases where you get them wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In the:
`if (file = NULL)`
You should put
`if (file == NULL)`

Because you want the result of a comparison (an equal), but instead you are assigning the `NULL` value to the variable.

Comment: Your compiler is likely telling you that if you have compiler *warnings enabled* (as you should). Always enable compiler warning (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang; and `/W3` for VS) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. (and see the original comment by @Osiris - using an incorrect *conversion specifier* is causing your read to fail and likely *Undefined Behavior*)